# Sequence bounds and limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm doing the following exercise.
Given the sequence
\begin{cases}
a_{n+1} = {n + 8\over4n + 1}*a_n  & n=0, 1, 2 \\
a_{0} = 1
\end{cases}
Find if the sequence is definitely decreasing/increasing.

Given
$A = \{ x \in R : x=a_n \qquad n=0,1,2\ldots\}$

Find 
$lim_{n->\infty} a_n$, upper bound of A and lower bound of A.

So i started by trying $a_n$
$$a_1={1+8\over4(1)+1}*1={9\over5}$$
$$a_2={2+8\over4(2)+1}*{9\over5}={10\over9}*{9\over5}=2$$
$$a_3={3+8\over4(3)+1}*2={22\over26}={11\over13}$$
$$a_4={4+8\over4(4)+1}*{11\over13}={12\over17}*{11\over13}={132\over221}$$
$$a_5={5+8\over4(5)+1}*{132\over221}={13\over21}*{132\over221}={1716\over4641}$$
Which seems to me to be definitely decreasing.
[image: graph of an]

$2$ is the upper bound and the point of max beacuse $2 \in A$.

$0$ is the lower bound but not the point of min beacuse $0 \notin A$.

It's that correct? Also i have to find $lim_{n->\infty} a_n$ but what is $a_n$?
My thought was:
$$a_n = {(n-1)+8\over4(n-1)+1}*{n+6\over4n-4}$$

But that doesn't convince me at all, and it's limit would be $1\over4$ wich is not what i expcted because i thought was $0$.
What am i missing?

Comment: Plotting the first values is a good starting point but cannot replace a proof. To find the ultimate variation, make sure that $a_n$ can never be 0 and find the limit of $a_{n+1}/a_n$. What does that say ?

Comment: where did you get the last expression for a_n from? (whose limit is 1/16 btw)

Comment: I don't know what "definitely" decr./incr. means but if it means   "strictly"/"everywhere", then neither condition holds since it increases first and decreases later.

Comment: @mathse it means ultimately -> there is a point after which the sequence is monotonous

Comment: Notice that for large $n$, $4n+1>n+8$ (actually for $n>7/3=2+1/3$ this is true). This means that the next termm of the sequence is obtained fromthe previous by multiplying by a number in $(0,1)$. Therefore, the next number in the sequence is always smaller than the previous one for $n>3$.

Comment: Since the sequence is 'definitely' (eventually) decreasing the maximum will be in a finite segment before it begins to decrease. So, in $n\in[0,3]$. You have already computed the balues of $a_n$ for those $n$. The maximum among them is the maximum.

Comment: Since the sequence is eventually (after $n=3$) decreasing the infimum will be the minimum between the minimum in $n\in[0,3]$ and $\lim a_n$. You have already computed a few values for $n>3$ and these are smaller than the values in $[0,3]$. So the infimum is $\lim a_n$ and it is not attained.

Comment: @T_O If the value of, say, $a_1$ were to be smaller than $\lim a_n$ then $a_1$, and not $\lim a_n$ would be the infimum. Notice also that when the infimum is the limit of the eventually decreasing sequence, there is no minimum, only infimum.

Comment: @Richard you are right I removed my comment

Comment: There are many ways to compute the limit. First I will write the first way it came to my mind to compute it. Later I will try a more elementary way. Notice $a_{n}/a_{n-1}\to 1/4$. Then $\sqrt[n]{a_n}\to 1/4$. This implies that $a_n\to 0$.

Comment: @T_O my problem is that i dont know what $a_n$ is, i have tried to get by replacing $n$ with $n-1$ and the last formula is what i came out to find.

Comment: @Ally you don't need to find the expression of $a_n$. Richard's explanation is complete

Comment: An elementary way to compute the limit could be: For $n$ large,say $n>10$, we can assume that $0<1/8<(n+8)/(4n+1)<1/2$. This is because the limit of that fraction is $1/4$. Now, for $n>10$ large we have $a_n=\frac{n+8}{4n+1}<1/2a_{n-1}<1/2^2a_{n-2}<...<1/2^{n-10}a_{10}$. So, $0<a_n<1/2^{n-10}a_{10}\to 0$. Therefore $a_n\to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

First, to find out if the sequence $a_n$ is decreasing or increasing, you need to calculate the ratio $r_n=\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and then compare it to $1$.

$$r_n=\dfrac{n+8}{4n+1}.$$

You can see that for $n\geq3$, $r_n< 1$. This implies that the sequence $a_n$ is decreasing.

For the lower and upper bounds of $a_n$: $(1)$ Since $a_n$ is nonnegative and decreasing $(2)$ Since $a_n$ is increasing from $0$ to $2$.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\leq a_n\leq a_2.$$

For the limit, I do not know how to calculate it.